# How can I match 2d array arguments using Mockito?

Tags: java, testing, mocking, mockito, powermock

I have this method I'm trying to mock:

```
public class Dog {
    public String foo(String a, String[][] headers);
}
```

I would like to return `bar` when `foo("hello", new String[][]{{"a", "b"}})` is called:

```
Dog dog = mock(Dog.class);
when(dog.foo("hello", new String[][]{{"a", "b"}})).thenReturn("bar");
```

However this doesn't work because Mockito uses `equals()` when matching arrays, and since they don't point to the same object it fails:

```
// prints null instead of bar
System.out.println(dog.foo("hello", new String[][]{{"a", "b"}}));
```

Note the code that is tested will not have access to the object used as the argument to be matched in `#when`. What are some ways to get around this problem?

Comment: I believe your problem is that the arrays in your implementation are not the same instance. Try assigning the array to a variable and use that variable in the "when" as well as in the "dog.foo" call.

Comment: Yep that's the problem, however the code that gets tested which will call dog.foo with those parameters won't have access to the array variable. It must construct a new array that will have the same values.

Answer (score 4):

Try using Matcher:

```
@Test
public void testsss() {
    Dog dog = Mockito.mock(Dog.class);
    Matcher<String[][]> matcher = new BaseMatcher<String[][]>() {
        @Override
        public boolean matches(Object item) {
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {
        }
    };
    Mockito.when(dog.foo(Mockito.eq("hello"), Mockito.argThat(matcher))).thenReturn("bar");

    Assert.assertEquals("bar", (dog.foo("hello", new String[][] { { "a", "b" } })));
}
```

Just implement your own matches method instead of returning true ;)

Comment: +1; you may find [Arrays.deepEquals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepEquals%28java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object[]%29) to be helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

you can try inline overriding of the class Dog:

```
  Dog dog = new Dog()
   { 
       public String foo(String a, String[][] headers){
     if (headers[0].equals("a") && headers[0].equals("b")) return "bar";
    }
}
```

then run your test on dog.
I know for sure that there is another solution using Mockito methods, but can't remember the syntax.